# Ramda - R.both with curried predicates

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

My goal is to link two predicates that take the same two parameters in a R.both such that I can pass the parameters independently - i.e. curried.

Here's the repl implementation I put together:

```
const isXEqual = (obj1, obj2) => R.equals(obj1.x, obj2.x);
const isYEqual = (obj1, obj2) => R.equals(obj1.y, obj2.y);

const a = R.curry(isXEqual);
const b = R.curry(isYEqual);

const isBoth_Curried = R.both(a, b);

const obj1 =  {"x": 6, "y": 5};
const obj2 =  {"x": 6, "y": 5};
const obj3 =  {"x": 5, "y": 5};

isBoth_Curried(obj1, obj2); //==> true
isBoth_Curried(obj1, obj3); //==> false

isBoth_Curried(obj1)(obj2); //==> true
```

**But:**  `isBoth_Curried(obj1)(obj3); //==> true`

Really confused - what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that R.both is not curried by default. If you do `R.curryN(2, R.both(a, b))` then it works as one expects. Look at this [REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/#?const%20isXEqual%20%3D%20%28obj1%2C%20obj2%29%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20console.log%28%27%20%20isXEqual%27%29%3B%0A%20%20console.log%28%60%20%20%20%20obj1%3D%24%7BJSON.stringify%28obj1%29%7D%60%29%3B%0A%20%20console.log%28%60%20%20%20%20obj2%3D%24%7BJSON.stringify%28obj2%29%7D%60%29%3B%0A%20%20console.log%28%27%27%29%3B%0A%20%20return%20R.equals%28obj1.x%2C%20obj2.x%29%3B%0A%7D%0Aconst%20isYEqual%20%3D%20%28obj1%2C%20obj2%29%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20console.log%28%27%20%20isYEqual%27%29%3B%0A%20%20console.log%28%60%20%20%20%20obj1%3D%24%7BJSON.stringify%28obj1%29%7D%60%29%3B%0A%20%20console.log%28%60%20%20%20%20obj2%3D%24%7BJSON.stringify%28obj2%29%7D%60%29%3B%0A%20%20console.log%28%27%27%29%3B%0A%20%20return%20R.equals%28obj1.y%2C%20obj2.y%29%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20a%20%3D%20R.curry%28isXEqual%29%3B%0Aconst%20b%20%3D%20R.curry%28isYEqual%29%3B%0A%0Aconst%20isBoth_Curried%20%3D%20R.curryN%282%2C%20R.both%28a%2C%20b%29%29%3B%0A%0Aconst%20obj1%20%3D%20%20%7B%22x%22%3A%206%2C%20%22y%22%3A%205%7D%3B%0Aconst%20obj2%20%3D%20%20%7B%22x%22%3A%206%2C%20%22y%22%3A%205%7D%3B%0Aconst%20obj3%20%3D%20%20%7B%22x%22%3A%205%2C%20%22y%22%3A%205%7D%3B%0A%0Alet%20ret%3B%0A%0Aconsole.log%28%27isBoth_Curried%28obj1%2C%20obj2%29%27%29%3B%0Aret%20%3D%20isBoth_Curried%28obj1%2C%20obj2%29%3B%0Aconsole.log%28%60%20%20ret%3D%24%7Bret%7D%5Cn%60%29%3B%0A%0Aconsole.log%28%27isBoth_Curried%28obj1%2C%20obj3%29%27%29%3B%0Aret%20%3D%20isBoth_Curried%28obj1%2C%20obj3%29%3B%0Aconsole.log%28%60%20%20ret%3D%24%7Bret%7D%5Cn%60%29%3B%0A%0Aconsole.log%28%27isBoth_Curried%28obj1%29%28obj2%29%27%29%3B%0Aret%20%3D%20isBoth_Curried%28obj1%29%28obj2%29%3B%0Aconsole.log%28%60%20%20ret%3D%24%7Bret%7D%5Cn%60%29%3B%0A%0Aconsole.log%28%27isBoth_Curried%28obj1%29%28obj3%29%27%29%3B%0Aret%20%3D%20isBoth_Curried%28obj1%29%28obj3%29%3B%0Aconsole.log%28%60%20%20ret%3D%24%7Bret%7D%5Cn%60%29%3B%0A%0A%0A%0A) to see an example.

Comment: OK I see that it works but I don't really understand why.  Two different questions:  1)  why doesn't currying the `a` and `b` work?  I feel like I'm not understanding something fundamental.    2) was playing with your REPL and saw that `R.curry(R.both(a,b))`  does not work.  Why do we need to constrain with `R.curryN`?

Answer (score 3):

I think Ramda's [`both`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#both) is slightly out of sync with the majority of the library (disclaimer: I'm one of the Ramda authors.)  The result of `both` probably *should* be curried to the maximum length of its arguments, as happens with its close affiliate [`allPass`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#allPass).  So this should work the way you expect.

But, I think you are missing something basic, as you suggest.  It doesn't matter that the inner functions are curried.  They will only be called once, with all arguments:

```
R.both(a, b)(obj1)(obj3)                 //~> [1]

(function () {
  return a.apply(this, arguments) && a.apply(this, arguments);
})(obj1)(obj3)                           //~> [2]

(isXEqual(obj1) && isYEqual(obj1))(obj3) //~> [3]

(isYEqual(obj))(obj3)                    //~> [4]

R.equals(obj1.y, obj2.y)                 //~> [5]

R.equals(5, 5)                           //=> [6]

true
```

The step that's most likely tripping you up is [3], `(isXEqual(obj1) && isYEqual(obj1))(obj3)` ~> `(isYEqual(obj))(obj3)`.  The point is that `isXEqual(obj1)` is, because of your currying, a function, as is `isYEqual(obj1)`.  Both of these are truth-y, so `&&` returns the second one.

That should explain what's going on.

I do think Ramda's `both` function should be updated.  But you can make this work, as others have suggested, by currying the result of `both`.

---

One more point: you can write `isXEqual`/`isYEqual` more simply with Ramda's [`eqProps`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#eqProps):

```
const isXEqual = R.eqProps('x')
const isYEqual = R.eqProps('y')
```

Comment: Bingo!  Yes step 3 was throwing me off.  Thank you for spelling it all out

Answer (score 1):

According the Ramda's source for `both`

```
var both = _curry2(function both(f, g) {
  return _isFunction(f) ?
    function _both() {
      return f.apply(this, arguments) && g.apply(this, arguments);
    } :
    lift(and)(f, g);
});
```

if the first parameter is a function, you are not returned a curried function.

Comment: Right but that's why I curried `f` (isXEqual) and `g` (isYEqual).   Should that return me a `f` and `g` that "waits" for the 2 arguments to be supplied?